# Is there any way to achive that Dimension.fillToConstraints behaviour without using ConstraintLayout in jetpack-compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I am practicing compose. I have a simple design which contains LazyColumn and TextField. All i want to do is making TextField fixed at bottom. The problem is since `MessageList()` composable doesnt have static height, it filles all screen and makes `TextField` disappear. I fixed that with using `ConstraintLayout` composable and setting  `MessageList()` height `Dimension.fillToConstraints`. I wonder is there any way to achive this with using only `Column()` not `ConstraintLayout`.

```
Column {
    MessageList(list, state)
    Footer(message) {
      message = it
    }
}

@Composable
fun MessageList(list : List<ChatItem>, state : LazyListState){
    LazyColumn(state = state) {
    .....
    }
}

@Composable
fun Footer(message : String, onChange : (String) -> Unit){
    TextField(value = message, onValueChange = onChange)
}
```

Comment: Did you try using ```Spacer(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(height)
            .fillMaxWidth())```

Comment: I just tried. It didn't help. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Please update the code with what you tried. Not sure whether my understanding is correct, but if the view height is dynamic, it should still scroll within a view bound right?  Now it's overlapping on the bottom view. Bottom view should be visible no matter what the overlapping view height is. Did you set the `Spacer` height to the bottom view height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
val itemsList = (0..60).toList()

Column {
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)){
        items(itemsList) {
            Text("Item is $it")
        }
    }
    Row( verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom) {
        Text(text = "Footer row")
    }
}
```

[image]